# Drupal9. Creando formulario personalizado. Pagina no encontrada

Tags: php, drupal, drupal9

tengo la siguiente estructura de directorios para mi **custom_form** dentro del directorio **modules** de mi proyecto de trupal 9: (https://gyazo.com/f614a6d0e8f1a8271dd57f4f082ec1dc).

**CustomForm.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_form\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;


class CustomForm extends FormBase{

  public function getFormId()
  {
    return 'custom_form_form';
  }


  function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $form['name'] = [
      '#type'=>'textfield',
      '#title'=>$this->t('name')
    ];
    $form['lastname'] = [
      '#type'=>'textfield',
      '#title'=>$this->t('lastname')
    ];
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type'=>'submit',
      '#value'=>$this->t('Send')
    ];

    return $form;

  }

  /**
   * Implements hook_form_alter().
   */
  function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('Good morning @fullname',['@fullname'=>$form_state->getValue('name').' '. $form_state->getValue('lastname') ]));
  }

}

?>
```

**custom_form.info.yml**

```
name: Custom Form
description: 'Create custom form'
package: drupaladicto

type: module
core_version_requirement: ^8.8.0 || ^9.0
```

**custom_form.routing.yml**

```
custom_form.form:
  path: '/miformulario'
  default:
    _form: '\Drupal\custom_form\Form\CustomForm'
    _title: 'My Custom form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

---

Despues de todo esto lo instalo en desde la interfaz en el apartado **aompliar**, lo detecta sin problemas, pero cuando lo isntalo y voy a la ruta `/miformulario` , me sale **pagina no encontrada**:
https://gyazo.com/48b0fb6a5e1c75dd3a684e085655f35a . Y deberia salir ahi el formulario.

Comment: Intenta en el archivo de ruteo con el requisito: `_access: 'TRUE'` en lugar de usar `_permission`.

Comment: Aunque tengas la configuración en el settings.php para desarrollo, cuando se crea una ruta es necesario borrar caché para que Drupal la reconozca. Dicho esto, tu error está en el routing.yml que has puesto "default" y deberías poner "defaults", en plural.